# How can extract the URLs which contains the post only from blogger websites

Tags: python, url, blogger, blogs, keyword

Suppose the list of URLs are like

https://website.blogspot.com/author/brew 
https://website.blogspot.com/what-is-the-average-salary-for-a-big-data-engineer.html 
https://website.blogspot.com/why-you-should-consider-big-data-the-potential-cost-savings.html 
https://website.blogspot.com/7-ways-big-data-can-benefit-your-business.html 
https://website.blogspot.com/contact-us 
https://website.blogspot.com/page/2 
https://website.blogspot.com/the-7-most-common-forms-of-big-data-and-how-they-can-help-you.html

From that list of 7 URLs I just want 4 URLs which are post URLs (2,3,4,7).
So What are the **keywords** from that I can conclude that which URL to include or Exclude

ex. For keywords like `/page/` `/about-us/` `contact-us` I will remove that URLs from list

In short I just want the extract the link of URLs having the post only, and exclude that  non-useful links.
So,
1. Where can I get the list of **keywords** 
 **OR** 
 2. Other way to extract that URLs

Comment: What are you extracting these URLs from?  Are you crawling the site?  Are you reading an XML sitemap?  Do you have a log file?

Answer (score 0):

Well for this website in particular it seems that posts end with `.HTML`

You could, however, run into some problems as

1. This might not be the case for all posts on the site
2. They might change it in the future